# How to enable Pages Collaboration on Mac?

Tags: icloud, pages

I am well connected with my iCloud Drive on my Mac but when I try to collaborate with a friend in a Shared document I receive the following error:

[image]

We have tried it both way:

- me sharing a document and sending her permission
- she sending me a document and sending me permission

When I log into [www.icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com), I can collaborate there.

It also tells me that I am offline:

[image]

But thats not true because I can create Folder, add files to our Shared folder from my Mac and it gets uploaded and is visible.

I am currently using Pages version 10.0.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a full-fledged solution, rather a step in the right direction- have you tried restarting your computer in Safe Mode? If there is a rogue app/or extension causing the issue then Pages will function correctly and you can start investigating the apps/extensions you have installed that might be the culprit.

[Apple Support- Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)

Comment: I tried this and didn't work

Comment: Just wanted to make sure. I will continue to some research on my end and get back to you with what I find.

Comment: In the AppleID section of System Preferences have you tried disabling and re-enabling iCloud Drive (or Pages specifically from the iCloud Drive options menu)? [See screenshot in link below.] 

https://share.icloud.com/photos/0uKSOxK2AzEqXm53Hfz6EK2bw

Comment: I have tried all yes